# How to display a lot of read only text in GWT?

Tags: gwt

I have a requirement to display a somewhat large amount of text, read only to the user. It can be up to a maximum of 500 characters, which isn't excessive, but it's still a lot. Since it's read only I was thinking of a label a versus text area box, if it can handle that much. Is there a better way to do this than I'm not aware of?
Thanks,
James

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either a `Label` or a `TextBox` will *definitely* be able to handle 500 characters.

Think of all the blog posts, Wikipedia articles, Stack Overflow questions, longer than that that have been written. They were all composed in a text box and displayed in a div. You'll be fine.

Comment: I wasn't thinking about that. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Label works fine. Just remember that the default css for white-space collapses whitespace rather aggressively. If your text includes line breaks you may want to switch to pre or pre-wrap.

The most straightforward (if not necessarily most correct) way to do that is:

```
    Label myLabel = new Label();
    myLabel.getElement().getStyle().setProperty("whiteSpace", "pre");
```

Note the Camel Case on the CSS attribute.

Comment: Thanks for all the responses. That is what I'll use.

Answer (score 1):

500 chars is no big deal so it will be ok. Label is ultimately calling `element.innerHTML = text` which is a browser-native Javacript function that can handle any amount of text.